# how to save score of a facebook game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to make a facebook game using facebook canvas and unity. But i feel a great difficulty to save game score for every level and retrive them and show them also wondering how to make a leader board and show friend score who player it .It will be greatly helpful if anyone help me with it .

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with the [FriendSmash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial) game, which represents a somewhat decent example of Unity and Facebook integration.
2. Read through the guide chapter "[Publish scores with the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial#)"
3. Look at the MainMenu.cs and GameStateManager.cs scripts from the FriendSmash demo for a good code example.

Key features:

```
private void PushScore() {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        query["score"] = Instance.score.ToString();
        FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, 
               delegate(FBResult r) { 
                  Util.Log("Result: " + r.Text); 
               }, query);
     }
}

private void QueryScores() {
    FB.API("/app/scores?fields=score,user.limit(20)", 
            Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, ScoresCallback); // check for the ScoresCallback in MainMenu.cs for sample implementation details
}
```

4. Check out the Facebook [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) reference for what are the URLs and the API elements that you need to use.